# Set up an alert for SQL Server database in Azure from Azure PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I am trying to create an alert for SQL Server so that whenever CPU percentage goes high, it should send an email and I have this code which sadly not working.

```
$ResourceGroup = 'pp-rg-cloud-dev1-aks'
$server = 'abcd'
$db = 'efgh'
$location = 'eastus'
$rid = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -ResourceName "$server/$db").ResourceID
$email = New-AzAlertRuleEmail -CustomEmail 'user@user.com' -SendToServiceOwner

Add-AzMetricAlertRule -Name 'CPU percentage' `
-Location $location `
-ResourceGroup $ResourceGroup `
-TargetResourceId $rid `
-MetricName 'dtu_consumption_percent' `
-Operator GreaterThanOrEqual `
-Threshold 90 `
-WindowSize '00:05:00' `
-TimeAggregationOperator Maximum `
-Action $email
```

but I get this error:

> Add-AzMetricAlertRule : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Creating or editing classic alert rules based on this metric is no longer supported. To learn about new alert rules see https://aka.ms/create-metric-alerts, Code: BadRequest, Status code:BadRequest, Reason phrase: Bad Request
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Add-AzMetricAlertRule -Name 'CPU percentage'
> - 
> - CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzMetricAlertRule], PSInvalidOperationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Alerts.AddAzureRmMetricAlertRuleCommand

No matter what I try, it always says that metric no longer exist. Is there any way I can find the alert name?

Comment: Seems like you have to use the *new* cmdlets for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/add-azmetricalertrulev2. I just followed the link provided in the exception.

Comment: I am not able to set up an alert for SQL database with same command structure. and getting this error message : 
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Couldn't find a metric named CPU percentage. Make sure the name is correct. Activity ID:
7b7b9eba-f392-4c4a-ac74-f9f94cf04c1a., Code: BadRequest, Status code:BadRequest, Reason phrase: BadRequest
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 `
+ CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script:

```
$ResourceGroup = 'IntroAzureSql'
$location = 'West US'
$server = 'msf-sqldb'
$db = 'MSFADMIN'
$rid = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -ResourceName &quot;$server/$db&quot;).ResourceID
$email = New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -CustomEmails 'mfal@dummy.com' -SendToServiceOwners
Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule -Name 'DTU90Check' <code>
-Location $location </code>
-ResourceGroup $ResourceGroup <code>
-TargetResourceId $rid </code>
-MetricName 'dtu_consumption_percent' <code>
-Operator GreaterThanOrEqual </code>
-Threshold 90 <code>
-WindowSize '00:05:00' </code>
-TimeAggregationOperator Maximum `
-Actions $email
```

Comment: Getting this error : 
Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Creating or editing classic alert rules based on this metric is no
longer supported. To learn about new alert rules see https://aka.ms/create-metric-alerts, Code: BadRequest, Status code:BadRequest, Reason phrase:
Bad Request
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule -Name 'DTU90Check'-Location $location -Res ...
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :